# Reschduling Flight UK to Pak without paying penality

Tags: airports, international-travel, airlines

How Can i reschedule my return flight UK to Pak without paying penality before time

Comment: Have you already booked this flight? Your question is slightly ambiguous and open to interpretation

Comment: Please give more information about your situation. We need to know the airline, the type of ticket and anything else that could affect the answer.

Answer (score 3):

All airlines **can** provide such a fare, but you have to pay for a higher cost fare type upfront.

While you select your ticket, all airlines will provide different fare options and list the costs for a date change. On that stage select the fare type which suits your flexible return date. Technically that may be free of cost but you will pay that cost upfront.

I doubt you will find any that charges the least and then charges 0 for a date change.

Comment: And let’s note the higher fares are usually steep. Easily twice the cost of fixed date flights